# Find all the duplicate items form the table

Tags: sql, sql-server

My **ProductsTable** has below data, same item with different number like below. Sometimes the description also slightly different

| ItemNo | ItemDescripition | Stock | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0012500 | Apple | 10 | 20 |
| 0012601 | Banana | 5 | 15 |
| 012500 | Apple | 10 | 18 |
| 00012500 | Apple | 10 | 16 |
| 00AM0120 | Mango | 10 | 11 |
| AM0120 | Mango | 10 | 12 |
| 000AM0120 | Mango | 10 | 15 |

I have to find all the duplicate items form the table with slight difference like some items having two zeros (0's) in the beginning and some having three zeros(0's).

This table is just of reference. My Actual table has around 25,000 rows. item numbers are of type `varchar` and some items in the table have alphanumeric item number

Comment: _Sometimes the description also slightly different_... give an example and how you plan to mark them as duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Assuming* that `ItemNo` can only contain numerical characters, then you could `CAST`/`CONVERT` the value to an `int` first, which will "strip" the leading zeros, and then get a `COUNT` of the number of rows:

```sql
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT ItemNo,
           CONVERT(int,ItemNo) AS ItemNo_int,
           ItemDescription,
           Stock,
           Price,
           COUNT(ItemNo) OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(int,ItemNo)) AS Dupes
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT ItemNo,
       ItemNo_int,
       ItemDescription,
       Stock,
       Price
FROM CTE
WHERE Dupes > 1;
```

---

Seems that *assuming* for a column called Item number, where all the examples contain only numerical characters, only containing numerical characters was *not* a safe assumption.

Instead, therefore, you could do something wonky with `REPLACE` and `LTRIM`:

```sql
WITH Replaced AS(
    SELECT ItemNo,
           REPLACE(LTRIM(REPLACE(ItemNo,'0',' ')),' ','0') AS TrimmedItemNo,
           ItemDescription,
           Stock,
           Price
    FROM dbo.YourTable),
Counts AS(
    SELECT ItemNo,
           TrimmedItemNo,
           ItemDescription,
           Stock,
           Price,
           COUNT(ItemNo) OVER (PARTITION BY TrimmedItemNo) AS Dupes
    FROM Replaced)
SELECT ItemNo,
       TrimmedItemNo,
       ItemDescription,
       Stock,
       Price
FROM Counts
WHERE Dupes > 1;
```

Comment: Some items in the table have alphanumeric item numbers.

Comment: You *really* should have given examples with that in your question then, @MMB . If you have a column called `ItemNo` (presumably Item Number) and only give examples with numerical characters, it's going to be assumed that your Number is a number...

Comment: I have updated the answer for you, @MMB .